# What happened to the markup in EditText?

Tags: android, textview

What happened to the markup in EditText?
I used 9path for image for background in EditText
CODE JAVA:
To be honest, I used to, nothing like that happened. And besides, I don't use 9path too often.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#0079e8">
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText" android:background="@drawable/register_before"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewTitle"
        android:hint="Имя"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:paddingLeft="23dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:background="@drawable/register_before" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp" android:hint="Фамилия" android:textSize="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="23dp"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:background="@drawable/register_before" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp" android:hint="Название вашего вуза" android:textSize="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="23dp"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText4" android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:background="@drawable/register_before" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp" android:hint="Ваш факультет" android:textSize="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="23dp"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText5" android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:background="@drawable/register_before" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp" android:hint="Номер группы" android:textSize="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="23dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: asddas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used 9patch for image for background in EditText CODE

Your 9-patch image is not created properly due to which it is showing the black shadow at the end. Try creating a proper 9-patch image by defining the center region as stretchable.

Generate your 9-patch from [here](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html).